# How to add SQL Server DATE type to code first migrations of a .Net Core Web API application?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, migration

I started to work on a .Net Core Web API application. I need to add a new table that should contain a `date` type. Since we're using code-first migrations I have to define this type in the C# models and I'm not sure how to do it.

In all the other models there are just `int`, `string` and `bool` types.

In several instances a `long` is used to store the datetime.

I don't want to use this method since I need to store just the day and be able to filter by month and whatnot.

Also we're using `Digipolis.DataAccess` if that provides some insight.

What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: I used Datetime for my model.

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. Thanks.